# Facebook PHP SDK V5 returns user access token as page access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get **PAGE ACCESS TOKEN** using facebook USER ACCESS TOKEN 
The Steps I have completed are

My Application path = http://localhost/facebook_req/

1. On my index.php I have successfully allowed my admin user to use the app using the below permissions 

   `<?php
   session_start();
   include('Facebook/autoload.php');
   $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array('app_id' => '{appid}',
                                     'app_secret' => '{appsecret}',
                                     'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7'));
   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
   $permissions = array('publish_pages','manage_pages','pages_show_list');
   $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/facebook_req/callback.php', $permissions);
   echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';`

2 When I click the log in with facebook I get the dialog and I allow as the I allow the app which I created on the callback.php file I used the getRedirectLoginHelper(), **retrieved/got the USER ACCESS TOKEN** printed the user access token & token metadata and finally tried to post to user account and it was successful (see below sample var_dump of my token metadata)

```
<code>
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = $accessToken->getValue();
D:\wamp64\www\facebook_req\callback.php:48:
object(Facebook\Authentication\AccessTokenMetadata)[13]
  protected 'metadata' => 
    array (size=7)
      'app_id' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=15)
      'application' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxx' (length=8)
      'expires_at' => 
        object(DateTime)[17]
          public 'date' => string '2016-11-03 11:35:38.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'is_valid' => boolean true
      'issued_at' => 
        object(DateTime)[18]
          public 'date' => string '2016-09-04 11:35:38.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'scopes' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string 'manage_pages' (length=12)
          1 => string 'publish_pages' (length=13)
          2 => string 'pages_show_list' (length=15)
          3 => string 'publish_actions' (length=15)
          4 => string 'public_profile' (length=14)
      'user_id' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=15)
</code>
```

3. This part is where it gets weird because I cant seem to get the **PAGE ACCESS TOKEN** when I tried to get the page access token using graph explorer it works but it doesnt work on my code

> ```
> ACCESS TOKEN - user access token received from step 2 callback.php file
> METHOD - GET
> FIELDS - nonupublic?fields=access_token
> This works on graph explorer
> ```

My php code returns **USER ACCESS TOKEN** instead of **PAGE ACCESS TOKEN**

```
<code>
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(....);
    $requestx = $fb->request('GET', '/nonupublic?fields=access_token',array(),$_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
    var_dump($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
    var_dump($requestx);
</code>
```

the issue is `var_dump($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);` and `var_dump($requestx);` are identical they aren't different and I cant seem to post to facebook page

by the way im following the guide on the document url - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens

could anyone please advice

Comment: Works fine here. I get a page access token without issues.

Comment: I think im mistaken at the code like $requestx is there a way to execute a request ?

Answer (score 0):

As @ceejayoz pointed out my code works Ive made a mistake I have constructed requests but did not execute them on facebook php v5 I need to execute requests

```
$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($requestx);
```

Everything works flawlessly